# Headless Fragment Issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to retain state of the multiple fragments in my project. Their parent is a single Activity and i need to implement the TaskFragment in all the Fragments but not the Main Activity.

In the worker-fragment example, an Activity is implementing the TaskCallback which works but how will it work with a fragment ?

https://github.com/alexjlockwood/worker-fragments

I am trying to implement TaskCallbacks in my fragments such that the interface's overriden  method call goes directly to the fragment like this :-

```
public class MyFragment implements TaskFragment.TaskCallbacks{
//Some Code
//Code for initializing TaskFragment
//Overriden method of Task Callback
}
```

However, when i do this, it is showing an Ilegal state exception in onAttach method of TaskFragment that **Activity is not implementing callback interface**.

How do i get the instance of the fragment which is implementing this Task Callback ?

Comment: your fragment does not extend `Fragment`.

Comment: So there is no way then to achieve this ?

Comment: What is that you are doing? i don't uderstand

Comment: why do you want to implement TaskCallbacks in `MyFragment`. you need to read his blog first http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Comment: Because i have a global navigation drawer and many fragment classes containing many service calls and i cannot write all those in the mainactivity itself. the code would become too obsolete.

Comment: you missed another point that fragment is attached and detached when orientation changes that is whole point of the blog. If you don't take care of that then you end up in trouble when orientation changes